# DNS server thinks it has no internet, but is running fine

Tags: domain-name-system, internet

I'm having a lot of issues googling my way to victory on this due to the verbiage.

[image: its wrong]

I currently have a single DNS server that seems to be running quite well and fine. It is however taunting me with this "no internet access" warning despite the internet working flawlessly. All computers in the forest are not experiencing any issues connecting to the DNS either. I fear that this issue may be causing issues that I am not easily noticing though.

Any information to point me in the right direction would be great.

[image: additional info]

Comment: Maybe it's strange, but maybe it's account consistency problem. Try [network icon says "no internet access" but i am connected](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-icon-says-no-internet-access-but-i-am/de3aeb88-1e19-4159-9ad8-c64e732e455a)

Comment: If you launch a browser and try to go to, say, "google.com", does it work?

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk the listed solution there made no change - logged in with user that had no existing profile. I may have to bite the bullet and try reinstalling the drivers as suggested in the unaccepted answer to rule that out.

Comment: @Remm I wanted suggest you reinstall drivers, but I thought that solution in link will help you.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk the wording of your link lead me to a lot more material to check that I wasn't finding in my initial (badly worded) google searches. Restarting the Network Location Awareness seems to have fixed it, but I believe it will only last until a restart. Will have to wait and see after users leave for the day. Thanks